# Dockerfile chown not working

Tags: docker, dockerfile, chown

I have a dockerfile setup

```
FROM node:8.10.0

USER node
RUN mkdir /home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH=/home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node.npm-global

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.8 ts-node@5.0.1

WORKDIR /opt/src
COPY . .

USER 0
RUN chown -R root /opt/src
RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "run", "build:prod"]
```

this runs fine locally, but when I try to deploy it, seems like the chown command didn't work, as it errors on npm install and shows

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/opt/src/node_modules/nodent-runtime/dist/index.js'
```

what could be wrong?

Comment: The `RUN npm install ...` is being run as user "node", as per `USER node` few lines above. Is this correct?

Comment: yes I believe so...

Comment: try `RUN chown -R root:root /opt/src` - as the /opt/src folder was created by the node user & the chown changed the owner only, not the group

Comment: Check out this angular-seed project which has Docker support in it.   https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed